# Magento Admin panel - Dropdowns not working/showing

Tags: javascript, magento, admin

After logging into my admin panel in Magento, the dropdowns in the admin panel are not showing up. JavaScript error console revealed some errors. After a bit of googling I have tried:

- changing permisions of js folder to `755`
- all .js files and index.php in js folder to `644`

Finally I also tried replacing the is folder with the original js folder of the Magento package. However nothing seems to work.

Comment: lack of information. what is the error message? was it ever working before?

Answer (score 0):

The reason why the dropdowns won't show is that Magento uses JavaScript to assign classes to the hovered menu elements and uses those classes in the CSS to show dropdowns. Errors in the javascript prevent from loading every other javascript that appear after the line with an error.

Don't replace js folder with default one - every new js that's there is there for a reason (it sounds like your website was customized, so removing js files responsible for custom features won't help you). Instead, you have to work on fixing every javascript error.

Please provide more data on those errors or a link to your website.